# Is there a MSVC version that can handle C inline structures?

Tags: c, visual-c++

I'm trying to do something like this in my C application:

```
struct MyColor
{
    int Color;
};

struct MyColor* RandomizeColor(struct MyColor* self)
{
    return self;
}

int main()
{
    struct MyColor* Color = RandomizeColor(&((struct MyColor){0}));

    return 0;
}
```

But MSVC++ 2010 Express gives me a "type name not allowed here". Is there another version that will do this? Or am I better off using another compiler? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you are trying to use is called *compound literals*. Compound literals is a C99 feature. The C compiler in MSVC package is an outdated C89/90 compiler, which does not not support C99.

You will have to use named objects in order to make your code compile with MSVC's C compiler

```
struct MyColor temp = { 0 };
struct MyColor* Color = RandomizeColor(&temp);
```

Or you can switch to another compiler that supports C99.

Comment: I updated to MS Visual Studio 2013 which does support compound literals, which will compile my code correctly.